# Blackberry Email Check Mark

Tags: html, email, unicode, blackberry

I am trying to use &#x2714 and &#2718 to get the check mark and cross in my HTML emails.  I am using Litmus to test the output and for some reason the Blackberry 5 OS shows ? (question marks) instead of the tick and cross.  All other email clients show the symbol as expected.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a font issue: the available fonts do not contain glyphs for these characters. Use other characters instead, or maybe small images.